# JSlider does not get added to JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, jslider

```
JSlider slider = new JSlider();
slider.x();
slider.domorestuff();

JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("X"));
label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(780, 100));
label.setVisible(true);
label.add(slider);

frame.add(label);
```

If I add the label I see a label with nothing in it.
If I add only the slider it will be displayed normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `JSlider` and `JLabel` are core components. You can't add `JSlider` on top of `JLabel`. Use container like `JPanel` to add `JSlider`.

Comment: What do you mean by Container?

Comment: Go to this link to learn about container and components. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html

Comment: JComponent can be added to another JComponent, is required to set LayoutManager, because only JPanel and JFrame has implemented this feature in API, but your suggestion to use JPanel is correct, please to delete "Two core component can not add one another.", then could be upvoted your answer here

Comment: The default Layout of JPanel is FlowLayout. You don't need to add other Layout manager for demo project. If your design requirement is different then use other Layout manager.